# xeokit-react plugin ifcLoader magic key error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ifc

I want to load an IFC file in my typescript react App with @xeokit/xeokit-sdk library but I'm getting this error :

`[xeokit plugin ifcLoader]: RuntimeError: Aborted(CompileError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): expected magic word 00 61 73 6d, found 3c 21 44 4f @+0). Build with -sASSERTIONS for more info.`

what is the magiv word how can I change it?

here is my component code:

```
import { Viewer, WebIFCLoaderPlugin } from "@xeokit/xeokit-sdk";

export default function BimViewer() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const viewer = new Viewer({
      canvasId: "myCanvas",
      transparent: true,
    });

    viewer.camera.eye = [-3.933, 2.855, 27.018];
    viewer.camera.look = [4.4, 3.724, 8.899];
    viewer.camera.up = [-0.018, 0.999, 0.039];

    const webIFCLoader = new WebIFCLoaderPlugin(viewer, {
      wasmPath: "../",
    });

    const model = webIFCLoader.load({
      src: "Duplex.ifc",
      edges: true,
    });

    return () => {
      viewer.destroy();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <canvas
      id="myCanvas"
      className="bg-gray-200 w-full h-full absolute"
    ></canvas>
  );
}
```